# how can i fetch the same column in two or more tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have multiple tables in all of them there is a column called "names".

i want to fetch all of the values in the "names" column. like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT names FROM nx1, nx2, nx3";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo $row ["names"];

         }
        } else {
           echo "‌empty";
         }
```

but i get this error:

```
 Notice
: Trying to get property of non-object in
```

sorry for this weird code i'm newbie :(

Comment: When you say 'row', do you mean 'column'?

Comment: Your object not have get() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select a column from multiple tables like that. In your case you want to use either UNION or UNION ALL (depending or result that you are trying to get).
[See the MySQL documentation for UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

In your case the query should look like this:

```
SELECT `names`
FROM   `nx1` 
UNION 
SELECT `names` 
FROM   `nx2` 
UNION 
SELECT `names` 
FROM   `nx3`
```

or

```
SELECT `names` 
FROM   `nx1` 
UNION ALL
SELECT `names` 
FROM   `nx2` 
UNION ALL
SELECT `names` 
FROM   `nx3`
```

The version with UNION ALL will keep duplicate rows while the version with UNION will remove them as if you used DISTINCT keyword.

Comment: it worked, but what if i wanted to DELETE instead of SELECT ?

Comment: My current code for DELETE is this:

DELETE FROM nx1, nx2, nx3 WHERE names='$names’"

Can you help me with this too ?

Comment: You can try `DELETE FROM nx1, nx2, nx3 USING nx1 INNER JOIN nx2 INNER JOIN nx3 WHERE nx1.names = nx2.names AND nx2.names = nx3.names AND nx1.names = '$names'`. But i've never tried that so i can't guarantee how it will work.

Comment: the first delete code you commented gave me this error

Error: DELETE FROM nx1, nx2, nx3 USING names WHERE names
Unknown table ’nx1' in MULTI DELETE

But the 2nd one gave me a long error

Anyway I will try to fix this myself since you never tried this one, thanks a lot